# DRY vs repetitive feature spec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've created a spec that tests how a user confirms his account. It tests the user in the following scenarios:

- can sign up
- can confirm his account if he gives the correct key
- cannot confirm his account if not signed in
- cannot confirm his account if his key is invalid
- cannot confirm his account if his key belongs to someone else.

While this code below is completely untested (wrote it all in the browser) I don't see why it wouldn't work. However, these are my concerns:

- It gets pretty hard to follow. I'm just testing a few scenarios here, and there are dozens more
- The indentation will get pretty insane as a result (5 or 7 nested scenarios)
- So how should I get around this? Should a feature spec actually not be so DRY?
- **Should a feature spec actually be somewhat repetitive? Should I do away with nested scenarios? Should each scenario be on the same 'level' with each scenario using its own, self contained before block that does occasionally have identical code to that in other before blocks? Doing this would be less DRY but more readable and easier to adapt.**

Again, this code has never even seen the light of sublime text so there may be some niggles:

**DRYer but harder to follow:**

```
describe 'user spec', js: true do
    before { visit root_path }
    let(:user){ FactoryGirl.build(:user) }       

    module Helpers
        def deliveries
            ActionMailer::Base.deliveries
        end

        def last_email
           deliveries.last
        end

        def sent_emails_count
           deliveries.count
        end

        def reset_action_mailer
           deliveries = []
        end

        def reload_user(user_name)

            User.find_by(user_name: user_name) # like to know how to write a method that could find by any attribute, not just username. E.g. `reload_user(email: 'thisismyemail@gotmail.com)`
        end

        def register_user(user)
           click_link 'sign up today!'
           fill_in 'user_user_name', with: user.user_name
           fill_in 'user_email', with: user.email
           fill_in 'user_password', with: user.password
           fill_in 'user_password_confirmation', with: user.password_confirmation
           click_button 'Register'
        end

        def sign_out(user) # I have a 'useless' user parameter in there to make code more self-documenting. E.g. sign_out(user_1), sign_out(user_2)
           click_link 'sign out'
        end

       def sign_in(user) 
           click_link 'sign_in'
           fill_in 'user_email', with: user.user_name
           fill_in 'user_password', with: user.password
        end
    end

# shared examples

   shared_examples_for 'a succeeded confirmation attempt' do |user|
       describe 'the page' do
           subject { page }

           it_should_behave_like 'profile_page'
           it{ should have_selector '.alert-success', text: "Thankyou for confirming! You're now a fully fledged user!" }
           it{ should have_selector 'h4', text: 'confirmed' }
       end

       describe 'the instance' do
           it_should_behave_like 'an confirmed instance', user
       end
   end    

   shared_examples_for 'a failed confirmation_attempt' do |user|
      describe 'the page' do
           subject { page }

           it_should_behave_like 'profile_page'

           it{ should have_selector '.alert-error', text: "Sorry, that key is wrong!" }
           it{ should have_selector 'h4', text: 'unconfirmed' }
       end



       describe 'the instance' do
           it_should_behave_like 'an unconfirmed instance', user
       end
    end

    shared_examples_for 'an unconfirmed instance' do |user|
        subject { reload_user(user.user_name) } 

        its(:confirmed_at){ should be_nil }         
        its(:state){ should eq 'unconfirmed' }
    end

    shared_examples_for 'a confirmed instance' do |user|
        subject { reload_user(user.user_name) } 

        its(:confirmed_at){ should eq Time.now }         
        its(:state){ should eq 'confirmed' }
    end


    scenario 'user signs up' do
       before do
           register_user(user)
        end

       describe 'the page' do
           subject { page }

           it_should_behave_like 'profile_page' # shared example that tests content and title. 
           it{ should have_selector '.alert-success', text: "welcome to the site, #{user.user_name}! Please check your inbox for a confirmation email. You won't be able to do anything untill you confirm your account!" }
           it{ should have_selector 'h4', text: user.email }
           it{ should have_selector 'h4', text: user.user_name }
           it{ should have_selector 'h4', text: 'unconfirmed' }

       end   


       describe 'the instance' do
           subject { User.last } #is this the best way to do this? I want to do `user.reload` but I can't reload user because the user is built in memory (doesn't go through ActiveRecord), and so doesn't have an id

           its(:confirmation_key_created_at){ should eq Time.now } 
           its(:confirmation_key){ should be_base64 } # my own matcher. No, I'm not an autistic maths genius, just testing it's 64 characters long ;)
           its(:state){ should eq 'unconfirmed' }
       end

       describe 'last email' do
          subject { last_email }
          # using email-spec matchers https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec

          it { should have_subject "Hi #{user.user_name}, confirmation link enclosed!" }              
          it { should deliver_to user.email }
          it { should have_body_text user.confirmation_key }

       end

       scenario 'then attempts confirmation by following the confirmation link in his email' do
           before do
              visit culminate_path(user.confirmation_key) # In order to closer emulate what the user would do, I would like to actually get the last email and use capybara to click the confirmation link, rather then emulating the click as I'm doing here. How could I do this?
           end

           it_should_behave_like 'a succeeded confirmation attempt'


       end



       scenario 'then attempts confirmation by following a made up link' do
           let(:user_2) { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

           before do
              sign_out(user)
              register_user(user_2) # could use FactoryGirl.create but this is an integration test. I want to emulate real-world events as much as possible 
              sign_out(user_2)
              sign_in(user)
              visit culminate_path(SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64) 
           end

           it_should_behave_like 'a failed confirmation_attempt'

       end 

       scenario 'then attempts confirmation by following a confirmation link for a different user' do
           let(:user_2) { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

           before do
              sign_out(user)
              register_user(user_2) # could use FactoryGirl.create but this is an integration test. I want to emulate real-world events as much as possible 
              sign_out(user_2)
              sign_in(user)
              visit culminate_path(user_2.confirmation_key) 
           end

           it_should_behave_like 'a failed confirmation_attempt'

       end 

       scenario 'then signs out and attempts confirmation by following the confirmation link in his email' do
           let(:user_2) { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

           before do
              sign_out(user)
              visit culminate_path(user.confirmation_key) 
           end

           describe 'the page' do
               subject { page }

               it_should_behave_like 'sign_in_page'

               it{ should have_selector '.alert-error', text: "Sorry, you need to be signed in inorder to attempt confirmation!" }
           end


           describe 'the instance' do
                it_should_behave_like 'a confirmed instance', user
           end

           scenario 'then signs in and visits link again' do
               before do   
                   sign_in(user)
                   visit culminate_path(user.confirmation_key) 
               end 

               it_should_behave_like 'a succeeded confirmation attempt'

           end
       end 
    end
end
```

**Easier to follow but not as DRY:**

```
describe 'user spec', js: true do
    before { visit root_path }
    let(:user){ FactoryGirl.build(:user) }       
    let(:user_2) { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

    # helper methods and shared examples hidden for brevity

    scenario 'user signs up' do
        before do
           register_user(user)
        end

       describe 'the page' do
           subject { page }

           it_should_behave_like 'profile_page' # shared example that tests content and title. 
           it{ should have_selector '.alert-success', text: "welcome to the site, #{user.user_name}! Please check your inbox for a confirmation email. You won't be able to do anything untill you confirm your account!" }
           it{ should have_selector 'h4', text: user.email }
           it{ should have_selector 'h4', text: user.user_name }
           it{ should have_selector 'h4', text: 'unconfirmed' }

       end   


       describe 'the instance' do
           subject { reload_user(user.user_name)} #is this the best way to do this? I want to do `user.reload` but I can't reload user because the user is built in memory (doesn't go through ActiveRecord), and so doesn't have an id

           its(:confirmation_key_created_at){ should eq Time.now } 
           its(:confirmation_key){ should be_base64 } # my own matcher. No, I'm not an autistic maths genius, just testing it's 64 characters long ;)
           its(:state){ should eq 'unconfirmed' }
       end

       describe 'last email' do
          subject { last_email }
          # using email-spec matchers https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec

          it { should have_subject "Hi #{user.user_name}, confirmation link enclosed!" }              
          it { should deliver_to user.email }
          it { should have_body_text user.confirmation_key }

       end
    end

    scenario 'a user signs up and then attempts confirmation by submitting a made up confirmation key' do

           before do
              register_user(user)
              visit culminate_path(SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64) 
           end

           it_should_behave_like 'a failed confirmation_attempt'

    end 

    scenario 'a user signs up and then attempts confirmation by following a confirmation link for a different user' do

           before do
              register_user(user_2)  
              sign_out(user_2)
              register_user(user)
              visit culminate_path(user_2.confirmation_key) 
           end

           it_should_behave_like 'a failed confirmation_attempt'

    end

    scenario 'then signs in and visits link again' do
           before do   
               sign_in(user)
               visit culminate_path(user.confirmation_key) 
           end 

           it_should_behave_like 'a succeeded confirmation attempt'
    end

    scenario 'a user signs out and then attempts confirmation by following the confirmation link in his email' do
       before do
          register(user)
          sign_out(user)
          visit culminate_path(user.confirmation_key) 
       end

       describe 'the page' do
           subject { page }

           it_should_behave_like 'sign_in_page'

           it{ should have_selector '.alert-error', text: "Sorry, you need to be         signed in inorder to attempt confirmation!" }
       end


       describe 'the instance' do
            it_should_behave_like 'an unconfirmed instance', user
       end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're right to eliminate most of the duplication. However, I would not use nested scenarios, since they require the reader to jump around in the file. I also wouldn't use shared examples, because they obscure control flow.

I'd do something like this:

```
describe "user signup and confirmation" do

  let(:user) { # whatever }
  before do
    register_user
    visit root_path
  end

  scenario "user signs up" do
    page_should_show_that_user_is_not_confirmed
    user_should_not_be_confirmed
    # Write assertions here to assert that confirmation email was sent
    confirmation_url = confirmation_url_from_email
    visit confirmation_url
    page_should_show_that_user_is_confirmed
    user_should_be_confirmed
  end

  scenario "user logs out before visiting confirmation URL" do
    # no need to do the same assertions as we did in the previous scenario before the visit
    confirmation_url = confirmation_url_from_email
    sign_out user
    visit confirmation_url
    page_should_show_that_user_is_confirmed
    user_should_be_confirmed
  end

  scenario "user attempts to sign up with an unknown confirmation key" do
    visit culminate_path("some garbage")
    page_should_show_that_user_is_not_confirmed
    user_should_not_be_confirmed
  end

  scenario "user attempts to sign up with the wrong confirmation key" do
    user2 = # whatever
    visit culminate_path(user2.confirmation_key)
    page_should_show_that_user_is_not_confirmed
    user_should_not_be_confirmed
  end

  def page_should_show_that_user_is_not_confirmed
    # Assertions
  end

  def page_should_show_that_user_is_confirmed
    # Assertions
  end

  def user_should_not_be_confirmed
    # Assertions
  end

  def user_should_be_confirmed
    # Assertions
  end

  def confirmation_url_from_email
    # Don't assert anything, just get the URL from the email
  end

end
```

It's relatively readable overall, and I think there's just enough duplication to maintain readability.

Comment: Hmm that's a pretty cool way of doing. Very readable and self-documenting.

Comment: Shoot, sorry Dave! :)